# how many $(symbol)annotations are there in salesforce Lighthing?

Tags: annotations

how many annotations are there in salesforce Lighthing? for example like :$A.enqueueAction(action). Can anyone tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The "old" lightning stuff (i.e. the Aura-based Lightning Components stuff and not the new Lightning Web Component stuff) is documented by Salesforce. There doesn't seem to be a single list of $ objects (these are not annotations), though [this lists global value providers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm) while you can find other details, including $A functions, through the [reference app](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_doc_app.htm).